# Given a pyspark dataframe containing hierarchy descriptions, how can I extract the complete hierarchy structure for a given ID?

Tags: python, pyspark, tree, table-structure

I have a table like below where the key column contains information on the hierarchy.

```
columns = ["structure_id", "position", "hierarchy", "key", "key_text"]
data = [(1, 101, 1, 10000, "Europe"), (1, 102, 2, 11000, "France"), (1, 103, 3, 11100, "Paris"), (1, 104, 2, 12000, "Italy"), (1, 105, 3, 12100, "Rome"), (1, 106, 1, 20000, "Asia"), (1, 107, 2, 21000, "Japan")]
df = spark.createDataFrame(data).toDF(*columns)
df.show()
#+------------+--------+---------+-----+--------+
#|structure_id|position|hierarchy|  key|key_text|
#+------------+--------+---------+-----+--------+
#|           1|     101|        1|10000|  Europe|
#|           1|     102|        2|11000|  France|
#|           1|     103|        3|11100|   Paris|
#|           1|     104|        2|12000|   Italy|
#|           1|     105|        3|12100|    Rome|
#|           1|     106|        1|20000|    Asia|
#|           1|     107|        2|21000|   Japan|
#+------------+--------+---------+-----+--------+
```

I want to get for a given structure id and position, e.g. structure_id = 1 and position = 105, the key text from that position and also from any upper levels, i.e. in this example [Europe, Italy, Rome].

The "real" data contains approximately 50 different structure ids and > 10 hierarchy levels.

I have transformed the original table in a very cumbersome way (lots of joins and temporarily creating a new column for each hierarchy level) into this:

```
#+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
#|structure_id|position|hierarchy|           key_array|
#+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
#|           1|     101|        1|            [Europe]|
#|           1|     102|        2|    [Europe, France]|
#|           1|     103|        3|[Europe, France, ...|
#|           1|     104|        2|     [Europe, Italy]|
#|           1|     105|        3|[Europe, Italy, R...|
#|           1|     106|        1|              [Asia]|
#|           1|     107|        2|       [Asia, Japan]|
#+------------+--------+---------+--------------------+
```

If the output format makes sense, I wonder how to efficiently transform the original table into this. Otherwise, I would like to know what would make sense, is it perhaps better to use a tree structure?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of a window and the collect_list aggregation like this:

```
ws = Window.partitionBy('structure_id').orderBy('hierarchy').rangeBetween(Window.unboundedPreceding, 0)

(
    df_original
    .withColumn('key_text_new', F.collect_list('key_text').over(ws))
    .show()
)
```

This returns the dataframe in the following format:

```
+------------+--------+---------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|Structure_ID|Position|Hierarchy|  Key|Key_Text|        key_text_new|
+------------+--------+---------+-----+--------+--------------------+
|           1|     101|        1|10000|  Europe|            [Europe]|
|           1|     102|        2|11000|  France|    [Europe, France]|
|           1|     103|        3|11100|   Paris|[Europe, France, ...|
|           2|     104|        1|20000|    Asia|              [Asia]|
|           2|     105|        2|21000|   Japan|       [Asia, Japan]|
+------------+--------+---------+-----+--------+--------------------+
```

Please note that I adjusted the Structure_ID from your example for Asia and Japan. I guess it should have been two from the key column that you provided.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I will adjust the question. The Structure ID does not change in this example (but the real data has about 50 different structure IDs). The window function doesn't work when there is more than one country.